# Percentages row tracks and gutters warning in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a line in my CSS that states: grid-template-rows: 20% 80%;

When I run the app in chrome I get a depreciation warning in the console. Not in Safari or Firefox.

"[Deprecation] Percentages row tracks and gutters for indefinite height grid containers will be resolved against the intrinsic height instead of being treated as auto and zero respectively. This change will happen in M70, around October 2018. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6708326821789696 for more details.
weather.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

I assume I can ignore this or do I need to add or change something in my CSS?

Answer (score 3):

In your `.css` file, find all instances of `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` and replace % amounts with `auto`, a fixed distance, or `1fr`. Once you do that, the browser console warning will go away.